# C# SocketException doesn't get caught

Tags: c#, try-catch, socketexception

i have a really weird sitation going on in my code. I'm developping a c# chat client-server application. When i close the server i want the client to be automatically closed. The client is reading from the TcpClient object using a StremReader. The client is in a while loop where it reads a line(StreamReader.ReadLine()) and then doing some operations with the line it reads.
When the serever gets closed, i also close the tcp connection server-side. So, i'm expecting the client to see a SocketException caused by the readline, catch it and exit. But the exception doesn't get caught!
Here's the client loop code:

```
 while (true)
 {
     try
     {
          ricev = read.ReadLine();
     }
     catch(SocketException exc)
     {
         //It never gets in here
     }
     chat.Invoke(showMessage, ricev);
 }
```

When i close the server, visual studio tells me that a "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" first-chance exception was raised in System.dll, but i cannot catch it. Why does that happen? i also tried to catch any generic exception with a

```
catch
{
}
```

block, but that doesn't work either.

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: after trying some more times, i actually found out that SocketException doesn't get raised at all. That's so weird, as i said in a comment, in the opposite situation, when the client gets closed before the server, the exception gets raised and i can canth it.
I don't really know what's going on....

Comment: Are you running this in the debugger?  A first chance exception is when an exception gets thrown but may be caught.  Second-chance exceptions are when it does not get caught and terminates the program.  Are you running under VS?  Or running it stand-alone?

Comment: Ought to work.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for CLR exceptions.  Wait for the debugger to break and start single-stepping to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Try adding a catch(Exception e) clause and see if it gets caught there

Comment: Im' running this inside VS in debug mode. I already tried using catch(Exception e) but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Did it break in the constructor for the `StreamReader`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well the scenario is when you call `Stop` method at `TcpListener` object "`_server.Stop()`", it will not throw `SocketException` at the client side when call `Read` on the stream... I don't know why this is happening but I have a work ground around it. it is by accessing to the underlying `Socket` on the `TcpListener` and call `Shutdown` on it:

```
_server.Stop();
_server.Server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);//now at your "read.ReadLine();" will throw SocketException
```

**Edit:** You stated at comment:

> actually i'm closing the tcpclient returned by the listener on the accept method. connClient.Close()

If are stopping the `tcpListerner` "`_server.Stop()`" and then close the `clients` getted from `_server.AcceptTcpCleint()` method, then at the at `reader.ReadLine()` will throw `IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall`  I tested it myself.

Comment: no, actually i'm closing the tcpclient returned by the listener on the accept method. connClient.Close(). Is this the right way to close a connection? From the documentation in visual studio, it says that the close method frees any resource of the TcpClient and asks for the underlying conneciton to be closed. Am i wrong? anyway, i will surely try to shutdown the socket and see if that works, thanks for the advice

Comment: @l.moretto: If you `closing the tcpclient returned by the listener on the accept method. connClient.Close()` then it will throw `IOException` at the `reader.ReadLine()`.. check my answer edit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I will try to do this. Anyway, i almost solved this by also checking if the readline returns a null string in the reading loop. if that happensa i break the loop. I also added a "finally" block which gets executed if i get an exception or the loop ends, so in any case i am now able to end the client program when the conneciton i closed by the server.

Comment: The `ReadLine()` method is block method that means it will block before you get your null or the string; _waiting_ for some data "a line" to be added so it can read it... i.e: you will not get the null or any data it just will block there as usual without throwing exceptions.

Comment: yes, but as soon as the connection gets closed it returns null, i tested that

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `Invoke`, odds are that the exception will be wrapped in a `TargetInvocationException`.

Answer (score 0):

> visual studio tells me that a "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException"
>   first-chance exception was raised in System.dll, but i cannot catch
>   it. Why does that happen?

First chance exceptions are intercepted by the debugger and interrupts you. It is the second chance exception that gets you into your catch block and that's why you do not get into your `catch` block on first chance. See this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx) for more information.

**Extracted from the article I mentioned above**

> **Does a first chance exception mean there is a problem in my code?** First chance exception messages most often do not mean there is a
>   problem in the code. For applications / components which handle
>   exceptions gracefully, first chance exception messages let the
>   developer know that an exceptional situation was encountered and was
>   handled.

On a side note, you can always configure your debugger to not stop on first chance exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the server socket, the other side receives a message of zero bytes. This indicates that the server has closed down properly:

> If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx

Exceptions are thrown only for exceptional situations - for instance if you reboot the server computer while your client was connected to it - not for normal program flow.

The `ReadLine()` operation should also not throw an exception but simply return `null` when this happens:

> **Return value**
>
> The next line from the input stream, or null if the end of the input stream is reached.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've this problem before and turn's out that I've been activate "Break when CLR Exception thrown and didn't uncheck it back"

So,check of you didn't uncheck this feature by
Press Alt+Ctr + E
scroll down to Common Runtime Language Exception and make sure to uncheck "Thrown" Check box.
I hope this help you.

Answer (score -2):

This is because .Net uses unsafe methods for Send/Receive methods.you have to handle your Program Coontext's `UnhandledException`